# function or way to convert euler rotation to fixed axis rotation ( world rotation )?

Tags: function, rotation, converters, euler-angles

I need function or way to convert `Euler` rotation to fixed axis rotation or converting fixed axis rotation to `Euler` rotation .
[Here is an example](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Euler2.gif) .

I have `Euler` rotation "XYZ" ( red arrow ) of the sphere and I want to know "XYZ" rotation of Fixed rotation world ( blue arrow ) or conversely .

Thank you .